# Why is new called an operator in Java?

Tags: java, new-operator

Why is `new` keyword called an operator in Java?

I know that `new` dynamically allocates memory in Java for an object and returns a reference to it but why is it called an operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the Java Language Specification does not call `new` an operator. It [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12):

> 38 tokens, formed from ASCII characters, are the operators.
>
> ```
> Operator:
>
>     =   >   <   !   ~   ?   :   ->
>     ==  >=  <=  !=  &&  ||  ++  --
>     +   -   *   /   &   |   ^   %   <<   >>   >>>
>     +=  -=  *=  /=  &=  |=  ^=  %=  <<=  >>=  >>>=
> ```

`new` is simply a [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) that occurs in a [class instance creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9).

I consider this a reasonable definition, as an operator would take operands (or, from the perspective of source code, appear next to an expression), but the class name followed by the argument list is not by itself a valid expression nor it is evaluated to produce a value at runtime.

I suspect the practice of calling `new` an operator originates from C++, where the new operator could be overloaded independent of the constructor call, to customize the memory allocation strategy. Managed languages such as Java or C# no longer allow such a separation, but the term operator has stuck.

For instance, the [C# language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) actually talks about a `new` operator, and specifies its precedence, but when actually specifying its meaning only talks about the 3 expression types than can be formed with a new keyword (object creation, array creation, and delegate creation expressions).

Answer (score 6):

Officially `new` is *not* an operator. There is no such word in the Java Language Specification, which is the sole authority in this matter.

There is the [*class instance creation expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), which involves the *keyword* `new`.

Comment: Yes you are right, i saw the link but in general terms we often say them operators, aren't we

Comment: It's because they call it like that in C++. I don't like the designation because what it "operates on" is not in itself an expression, and it is the essence of an operator that it operates on subexpressions.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is indeed an operator. It is a reserved keyword in Java, so you can't override it like you can override methods. It operates on class names - for a given class name it returns a new instance of the class. It's like the unary `-` (minus) operator which takes an integer and returns another integer (one with opposite sign), only that for new, the input and output are of different kinds.

Answer (score 0):

It's an operator, isn't it?

You could create instances like this:

```
A some = A.new(); // This wouldn't be an operator but just a built-in method
```

Or instead of `new` it could be `+`

```
A some = +A();
```

But in Java and other popular languages, they decided to implement an operator to create instances of classes and this was the so-called `new` *operator*.