# How does the new operator create a new object?

Tags: java

I've just started learning Java and I'm a bit confused about the syntax used for creating new objects.

Take the following:

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass(1, 2, 3);
```

What exactly is the syntax that comes after `new`? Is that the constructor call itself or is it just the class name with some arguments? Does `new` look at that and know what constructor to call based on those arguments or is the `SomeClass(1, 2, 3)` the constructor call itself?

I would like to know what steps are followed when `someObject` is created and what `new`'s role is.

What I don't understand is... is `SomeClass(1, 2, 3)` after `new` the actual constructor call on that same line? Or is it called later by `new`?

Update:

The source of my confusion has probably been the terminology used behind `new`. As it turns out, `new` is not an operator at all. `new` is actually a keyword. That makes much more sense to me now.

This answers my question: [Why is new called an operator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898748/why-is-new-called-an-operator-in-java)

Comment: This is heavily documented in any tutorial, reference book, documents, etc. Java tutorials says: `The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.`

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify my confusion.

Comment: My previous quoting and the provided answer are clear about it.

Comment: So to be clear, `SomeClass(1, 2, 3)` is just syntax but the constructor is actually called later?

Comment: 1) allocate memory for a `SomeClass` object 2) then call the appropriate constructor on it.

Comment: You should not really think of `new` and `SomeClass(1, 2, 3)` being two parts here (neither of them would be valid by themselves), the syntax is `new SomeClass(1, 2, 3)` as a whole.

Comment: But there are two parts. What is the new operator "operating" on here? Is the `new` operator's operand the actual constructor call? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: I think you're mixing the concepts of syntax and execution though. How an instance creation expression is written vs how it is executed are different things, only slightly related to each other. Btw JVM instruction [`new`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.new) takes *no* operands (as you can see in the operand stack diagram) and encodes the type it is creating as a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new`, the specified Type (`SomeClass`), the brackets `()` and possibly arguments etc. are part of one expression, according to the JLS "[Class Instance Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)".

So it does not make sense to separate `new` and the parts of the expression.

(But the arguments to the constructor are evaluated after memory allocation but before the call to the constructor.)

Comment: To be clear, `SomeClass`, the brackets `()`, and the arguments are *not* the constructor call expression itself right?

Comment: It's just "syntax" that is used as part of the class instance creation expression?

Comment: @AsadMoosvi: I am not sure what you mean with "syntax", but `new SomeClass(1, 2, 3)` is a "Class Instance Creation Expression". If you analyze them further, you can say that `new` is a keyword, `SomeClass` a "TypeDeclSpecifier" according to JLS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It does invoke the constructor of the object. *Instantiating a Class* as explained in [Object creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html):-

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new
>   object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also
>   invokes the object constructor.

The new operator requires a single, postfix argument: *a call to a constructor*. The name of the constructor provides the name of the class to instantiate.